# Unable to get the dropdown value in selenium websdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing the test script of signup page where i have to select date of birth from drop down calendar an i am able to select the DOB but can get the selected value. below is the code that i have written.

```
public void testcaes2(){
        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cat_id.req")));
        dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
        dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
  }
```

Comment: can you share the relevant HTML?

Comment: You do realize that you are calling `.getText()` and doing nothing with the returned value?

Comment: here is the site URL and option is select category http://talentrack.in/register

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below:

Note: Try to use xpath rather than CSS celector.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
    public void clickOnDropDown() throws InterruptedException {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='state']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void clickOnparticularOptionInTheDropDown() throws InterruptedException {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article/form/div/div/form/div/div[3]/div/div/select/option[42]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```